# Solving for exponent and denominator

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

Is it possible to solve for $r$ in this equation?

$$
v = \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}
$$

I *think* it's not... I spent some time trying to wrestle with various substitutions and couldn't get there. I can solve for $r$ practically by writing a program to interpolate but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

If it's not solvable, is there something about the form of the equation I should be able to recognize to know it's not solvable?

(Trivia: This is actually for a choose-your-own-adventure or "branching" novel; wondering whether I can solve for "choices per chapter" *r* given a number of chapters *v* and an average thread length *n*.)

Comment: You are tacitly asking whether $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}r^m=v$ has a solution.  It has $n-1$ solutions.  If you are asking whether one can find those solutions in closed form, the answer is yes for $n-1\le 4$.  I doubt that $r^n-vr+v-1=0$ has a closed form solution.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving a polynomial equation, as we have $$1-r^n=(1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1})\\ \implies v=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1}$$

Comment: @AndrewChin That expression is a tautology.  It is true for all $r$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456022/a-question-about-geometric-series-progressions

Comment: Yes, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902720/exact-solution-for-rate-parameter-in-finite-geometric-series answers my question as well. And teaches me this is a geometric sum. Thank you. Approximation is the way to go.